# jsFiddle preview for Stack Overflow

Tags: script

### Screenshot

[image]

### About

Adds embedded jsFiddle preview to the questions/answers posts by clicking on *Show jsFiddle button*

#### License

MIT License.

#### Download

- [Direct link at userscripts.org](http://userscripts.org/scripts/source/136983.user.js)
- [Project at userscripts.org](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/136983)
- [Project at GitHub](https://github.com/antyrat/stackoverflow-jsfiddle-preview)

#### Platform

Should work in Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox (with installed Greasemonkey extension) and Opera and others browsers that supports user scripts.

More about installation info at [`scripts`](https://stackapps.com/tags/script/info) wiki tag.

### Contact

See my [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/186535/antyrat) at stackoverflow for contact details.

### Code

JavaScript (jQuery)